# Java:Method called from subclass in superclass constructor

Tags: java, inheritance

```
class AA{
    int x;
    protected AA(){init (1008);}
    protected void init(int x)
    {
        this.x = x;
    }
}

class BB extends  AA{
    public BB() {
        init(super.x * 2);
    }
    public void init(int x)
    {
        super.x = x+1;
    }
}
public class Main  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BB tst = new BB();
        System.out.println(tst.x);
    }
}
```

I know that this code will print 2019. Yet I do not understand why the superclass constructor,when called, will use the init method from de subclass instead the one from the superclass.

Comment: why should it not do this? The subclass is a specialization of the superclass, any instance is `BB` with properties inherited from `AA`. But some have been overwritten by you.

Comment: @AKSW "why should it not do this?" It is choice of the language design. C++ takes a different approach where virtual functions overridden in subclasses are not called during superclass construction (presumably because unassigned variable are undefined in C++ but have default values in Java (even if `final`)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Yet I do not understand why the superclass constructor,when called, will use the init method from de subclass instead the one from the superclass.

Because that's the one associated with the object being constructed. `this` within the superclass constructor is a reference to the subclass object being constructed, so just like any other call to `init` using that reference, it uses the subclass's `init`.

This may help, note the lines with comments on the end — the comments say what those lines output:

```
class AA{
    int x;
    protected AA() {
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getName()); // "BB"
        System.out.println(this instanceof BB);        // true
        init(1008);
    }
    protected void init(int x)
    {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
class BB extends  AA{
    public BB() {
        init(super.x * 2);
    }
    public void init(int x)
    {
        super.x = x+1;
    }
}
public class Main  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BB tst = new BB();
        System.out.println(tst.x);
    }
}
```

It's because subclasses can override methods that calling non-`final`, non-`private` methods from a constructor is usually best avoided.